# Cant get contents of <body> tag to show for coldfusion builder 2 extension dialog

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

Here is my code...

```
<cfoutput>
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/xml">  
<response showresponse="true" status="success">  
<ide handlerfile="deploySvnPart2.cfm">  
<dialog width="550" height="500" title="Amend Contents of Temp Dir"/>  
<input name="go" Label="Checked"  type="boolean" />

<cfsavecontent variable="moo" > 
<![CDATA[  
<p style="color:black;">Any HTML content</p>  
]]>
</cfsavecontent>  
<body>#moo#</body>  
<input name="go" Label="#len(moo)#"  type="boolean" />
</ide>
</response> 
</cfoutput>
```

When the user is shown this page they only get the 2 inputs showing, but not the contents of the body tag.

This is contained in a .cfm page and is shown upon the user making some initial chocies from the first screen (defined in the idg_config.xml)

Is there any reason the contents of the body tag wouldnt show up?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the CDATA block? In the examples I see the developer did not use a CDATA block.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Ill try it, sorry i havent got back earlier.